# Can Empathy show what Rhythmbox track I'm listening to?

Tags: rhythmbox, empathy

There was an MSN Messenger feature that would show what track you were currently listening to. 
I'm using Rhythmbox as my music player.
Does Empathy have this feature?

Comment: Might be helpful if you say which music player you're using.

Answer (score 13):

You can also just open the *Edit ➜ Plugins* menu in Rhythmbox and enable the "IM Status" plugin. Worked instantly for me.

[image]

Comment: This sent the track as a status to Empathy? Do you have to do anything in Empathy? I've turned on the plugin, restarted both rhythmbox and empathy, restarted computer; it still doesn't show anything other than 'Available'. Has it been tried in Ubuntu 13.04? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Empathy Doesn't Have a plugin system so there are no plugin's that will interface with empathy.

However there is a **Rhythmbox plugin** that interfaces with **pidgin** that will do what you want called **Rhythmidgin** they have an installation guide on there launchpad page [here](https://launchpad.net/rhythmidgin)

Hope this helps