# How can I be notified of what music a friend is listening to?

Tags: music, clementine

A friend and I both use Ubuntu (and Windows when he's at work). In order to keep tabs on what the other is listening to, is there a way notifications of the currently-playing track of another person over the net can be shown in Ubuntu?

We currently use the Clementine music player (Windows and Ubuntu), but I'd be open to alternatives if that can't be used. Pidgin can be set to display the track in the status, of course, but an OSD message would be great.

Perhaps using a web app in the middle like last.fm might facilitate this somehow?

Answer (score 2):

I don't know about clementine, but both rhythmbox and banshee supports this kind of integration with a plugin. I don't use both banshee, rhythmbox or clementine but as far as I remember I think rhythmbox and banshee have instant messenger integration plugin in their preference. If you can't find it:

[here is status plugin for banshe](http://www.madsoft.org/2008/06/23/small-bashee-10-status-plugin-for-pidgin/)

[here is status plugin for rhythmbox](http://code.google.com/p/pidgin-rhythmbox/)

Edit: see [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/28185/can-empathy-show-what-rhythmbox-track-im-listening-to) thread on rhythmbox and IM status

Comment: Thanks, but it's actual OSD notifications which I'm after rather than just making the track available in a IM status.

Answer (score 0):

I think last.fm is a great idea.  I like that it updates the same place whether I'm listening on the computer or using my phone.  I can't speak beyond Android, but most Android media players can update last.fm.

You're looking for true "push" notifications, I'm not aware of any.  The main options seem to be last.fm or IM status updaters as sagarchalise suggested.

Last.fm is also interesting for the stat collection.  So after a while you might notice your friend likes a particular artist.  You can click through their profile to also look at which of that artist's songs they've played the most.  Or look at your own habits.  It's pretty neat.

Comment: Thanks. I suppose we could do something like http://sameerkhansblog.blogspot.com/2009/02/tweet-song-track-twitter-computer-auto.html and then set up a twitter client to show OSDs, but it's an awfully long way round. :)

Answer (score 0):

When I used meego that had a last.fm client that like twitter used to show what friends were listening to alongside twitter updates. Really good but it used to get in the way after a while